# Why is this IF statement crashing my php?

Tags: php, if-statement

Inside my php file I have this statement:

```
if($_POST['married'] === true) $married = 'yup' else $married = 'nop';
```

But if I do not comment it, my php result page becomes empty. It practically crashes.
I am POST-ing from a different place to this PHP, and in the POST values I have the "married" value. It is indeed empty (not true or false) but this has nothing to do with it.
I tried it this way too:

```
if($_POST['married'] === '') $married = 'yup' else $married = 'nop';
```

same result. Blank page.
Is there something wrong with my syntax? I cannot see my problem.
Please help me.

Comment: Check you error logs for details; but I expect it is because you are trying to `if else` in one line without using the command seperator `;`.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` are probably going to reveal to you that you have syntax errors in your code (hint: missing semicolons).

Comment: `if` statements don't **crash**. this is a simple syntax error.

Comment: The note says this topic is closed because it is off topic.  I disagree.  I'm dealing with a problem in that PHP handles conditional logic differently on a PC than it does in Ubuntu.  This appears to be an issue with an unclear PHP specification.  Thus, the question demonstrates "a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" and is a fairly common problem in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a semicolon after `$married = 'yup'` and use `isset` to determine whether the `$_POST` value is set:

```
if(isset($_POST['married']) && $_POST['married'] == true)
    $married = 'yup';
else
    $married = 'nop';
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not using `if` correctly.

```
if($_POST['married'] == true)
{
    $married = 'yup';
}
else
{
    $married = 'nop';
}
```

also `===` cannot be used for POST, as it automatically posts everything as a string; the `===` comparator compares data types, as well as content.

Comment: Everything in `$_POST` **is** string so `===` is perfectly fine though unnecessary.

Comment: Not if he's comparing a String to a Boolean, like above?

Comment: The original post was obviously changed (there were no booleans involved) but still claiming that "=== can't be used for POST" is wrong no matter how you look at it.

Comment: If he was comparing a string to a string, then yes he could use the `===` comparator. However, comparing to a boolean will always return false with `$_POST`

Comment: And also, all of this was in response to `if($_POST['married'] === true)` which is still in the opening question.

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that saying "=== cannot be used for POST" is wrong.

Comment: Well, you're never going to receive any other form of data type except String, so it's effectively a waste of a character. Ergo, useless.

Comment: Except its everything else but useless. Unit testing assertions, form data security checkups etc. all use this kind of strict type checking.

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon buddy!!

```
if($_POST['married'] === '')  $married = 'yup'; else $married = 'nop';
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to put semicolon just behind 'yup'.
it'll be

```
 if($_POST['married'] === true) $married = 'yup'; else $married = 'nop';
```

or, if you wish to use oneliner, then:

```
 ($_POST['married']===true)?($married = 'yup'):($married = 'nop');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that one-liner be `$married = $_POST['married']===true?'yup':'nop';`?

Comment: Well, this is another option. Yours is much clearer, and readable, i think.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a semicolon after each statement:

```
if($_POST['married'])
    $married = 'yup';
else
    $married = 'nop';
```

You may also want to check if it is set first using `isset`:

```
if(isset($_POST['married']) && $_POST['married'] === true)
    $married = 'yup';
else
    $married = 'nop';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

You could also write the statement using tenary:

```
$married = isset($_POST['married']) && $_POST['married'] === true ? 'yup' : 'nop';
```

More on the tenary operator: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/

Answer (score 1):

You missed the semicolon inside the if statement and try to check whether the $_POST variable is set or not

```
if(isset($_POST['married']) === true) 
  $married = 'yup';//Here you missed the semicolon
else 
  $married = 'nop';
```

Comment: I gave everybody a thumbs up. It was the semicolon. I am impressed by the speed with which all of you answered. It only took you 2-4 minutes to see my question and answer it. That is beautiful. I will accept the first answer. I do not agree with the lack of research downvote. I did research a lot on google, but missed the darn semicolon :( Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `show_errors = false` so it's silently bombing? If so (during development) make sure to turn [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on.

With that said, you should *always* check `$_POST`/`$_GET` values before using them. e.g.

```
$married = isset($_POST['married']) && ((bool)$_POST['married'])
         ? 'yup'
         : 'nop';
```

Answer (score 1):

empty operator will help you:

```
if(!empty($_POST['married'])) {
  $married = 'yup';
}
else {
  $married = 'nop';
}
```

Comment: this is not equivalent: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php and bTW doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I assume that field 'married' is an checkbox - most cases, when browser send checkbox field it puts string 'on' (or string from `value` attribute). It is not a boolean `TRUE` but string. If checkbox is unchecked then browser sends empty value or skip this key at whole. So `empty` is better choice for user1137313. Type comparisons is not a subject for this post... empty/not empty is not a subject too - user1137313 forgot about semicolon before else :)

Comment: just tell that for the OP (expand your answer). teach him how to fish, don't simply give him a fish

Answer (score 1):

Your page is crashing because semicolon is missing.

`if()` doesn't requires semicolon because it is a clause  not statement. 
`$married = 'yup'` is a statement which requires semicolon (;) to terminate.